# How can I constrain a type (kind?) to product types only

Tags: haskell

I'm looking into using monad comprehensions to represent SQL queries, and generate the appropriate SQL. At first glance, this is not a problem, it seems a good fit. But I have to restrict the types, which can form the monad to products only, no sums, and I can't think of a way to place such constraints.

I want to use the type checker to ensure that only types representable in SQL can be used.

I could, I suppose, use template haskell to derive the correct instances, and refuse to derive if the type does not fit, but I would prefer it done in the type level. Less chance for me introducing bugs due to my ignorance.

How could I do this? If yes, could you recommend some reading and/or code examples please.

**Edit:** Thanks, I've got some good paths to follow, which require more reading :) And here comes a long weekend.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately, this isn't really possible: a `Monad` must be fully polymorphic. It's the same reason you can't make `Set` a monad (the `Ord` constraint).

If you can deal with only having the result type meet the constraint, then you could have have `runSQL :: (Product a) => SQL a -> IO a`, or similar. In that case, just deriving the appropriate instances with Template Haskell is the way to go, or alternately, using the new [GHC Generics](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Generics); plain Haskell has no way to determine whether a type is composed of only products.

But I suspect you need to access the entire structure of the monadic computation, to translate it to SQL. Unfortunately, monads aren't very well-equipped to this, since they are plugged together with arbitrary Haskell functions, which you can't "look inside". [Arrows](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Control-Arrow.html) are closer, and let you do more static analysis, but still have that pesky `arr` that, again, lets you sneak in arbitrary Haskell functions.

The most viable option for doing something like this is probably to write a Template Haskell splicer to parse the syntax you want; you can say `$(sql [| [ (a,b) | a <- table1, b <- table2 |])` and have `sql` translate the AST to the corresponding SQL at compile-time If that syntax is too ugly, you write use a quasiquoter with [haskell-src-meta](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/haskell-src-meta), which would look like `[sql| (a, b) | a <- table1, b <- table2 |]`.

You might also be interested in the [generalised arrows](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~megacz/garrows/) extension, although it's probably overkill (and too experimental) for your purposes.

Comment: Thanks @ehird, that does give me food for thought. And, yes, I think restricting the result type might be sufficient. The Product class represents an SQL row, which is the result of a SQL SELECT query, and for queries without joins this should be enough. 

I'm trying to work towards a mini DSL, and my initial hope was to reach a stage, where the result of _runSQL_ is an acceptable query string. So something along the lines of  `(Product a) => runSQL::SQL a -> a`. Leaving the query execution to whatever a db backend does.

Comment: Sorry, in the above the function def should read  `runSQL:: (Product a) =>SQL a -> AST a` for some `AST a`

Comment: Monads don't have to be fully polymorphic anymore, with [constraint kinds](http://blog.omega-prime.co.uk/?p=127), do they? Don't know if these are applicable to the OP's problem, though.

Comment: @leftaroundabout: Yes, they do. Constraint kinds just let you define a restricted monad typeclass more easily; it was still possible without them, just a lot uglier. The standard `Monad` typeclass doesn't support such restricted monads.